# sum value of element

Tags: xslt

I need to add a number of values​​, depending on the content of each item. for example.

```
<links>
<test element="32"/>
<test element="17"/>
<test element="13"/>
<test element="11"/>
<test element="9"/>
<test element="8"/>
<test element="7"/>
<test element="7"/>
</links>
```

Total element: **8**, sum of the values ​​of each element: **104**, the value a show is this(104).

```
  <xsl:template match="//x:span[@class='ws-filter-count']">
    <xsl:variable name="countProduct" select="normalize-space(translate(text(), '()', ''))" />
    <xsl:variable name="sum" select="number(0)"/>
    <test element="{$countProduct}" />
  </xsl:template>
```

This sum:

Will this only be done with call-template?, recursive, correct?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="links">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(test/@element)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<links>
  <test element="32"/>
  <test element="17"/>
  <test element="13"/>
  <test element="11"/>
  <test element="9"/>
  <test element="8"/>
  <test element="7"/>
  <test element="7"/>
</links>
```

#### Output

```
104
```